# Security risk of passing a GUID via URL

Tags: asp.net, security, guid

I am after some advice regarding use of GUIDs from the security perspective.  I have developed an ASP.Net application.  It provides the user with access to some material, such as documents and photos, that aren't on the web server.  These are stored on a file server.  I have a 'GetResource.aspx' page which takes the ID of the resource, opens it using System.IO.FileInfo writes it to the response stream and returns it.

So, GetResource.aspx?id=123 would return, say, a picture that the user has access to.  Of course, the user could manually enter the URL as GetResource.aspx?id=456 in which case the picture / document etc with that ID would be returned and it may not be one they have permission to access.

So clearly using an integer ID is not adequate.  Would using a GUID as the ID provide enough 'randomness' that I could reliably assume the user could never manually enter "GetResource.aspx?guid={A guessed guid}" and ever expect to access a valid resource, including if using a script that made many random guesses per second?

Or, is there no substitute to determining the ID of the user from a Session variable, determining he does actually have access to the requested resource and only then returning it (Which as I write this I'm more and more convinced is the case!).

Thanks

Comment: Almost exactly the same as [Does using GUIDs for IDs make IDs unpredictable?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/31126/17306)

Comment: Thanks Kobi, I hadn't seen that and agree they are similar.  Thanks to everyone that answered too, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is certainly no substitute to authenticating the user and seeing if they are authorized to access the resource. What you are proposing here is a method of making it harder for a user to hit on a valid id for a document they are not authorized to view (either by mistake or on purpose).

A GUID is certainly large enough that you would never get "accidental" valid ids in practice. That makes a GUID without authorization checks a system that works great as long as noone is actively trying to break it. On the other hand, authorization checking is a system that would work great even in the presence of active attackers (of course this depends on what the attackers can manage to do).

You should choose between the two approaches depending on the nature of your application (is it public? are the users known and accountable for their actions? how bad would a "security breach" be?).

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is a very balanced answer which raises some good points including the distinction between accidental and someone actively trying to break it.

Answer (score 6):

You should be determining if the user is authorised before blindly serving it if it is protected content.

The GUID does help to some extent, it makes guessing URLs harder, so I'd still recommend using them. But URLs can still be shared (even accidentally). If you are just going to serve up the content anyway regardless of who makes the request then it is of little real protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that content is restricted one and having some personal data then you should go with username and password thing.